# Unable to present view controller from Floaty action button

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using [Floaty](https://cocoapods.org/pods/Floaty) cocoapod to add a floating action button to my iOS app but I am unable to get it to present a view controller. I'm using the global button as I need the floating button to be available on all screens. I've tested my view controller instantiation method using a normal button on a different screen that doesn't use the Floaty button and it presents it OK that way - can anyone explain why I am unable to present a view controller from my Floaty button? The handler I set for the button hits `openFile()` but doesn't do a thing, even though I don't have any difficulty instantiating the view controller this way on another screen.

```
func setLayout() {
    var floatItem = FloatyItem()

    floatItem.handler = { [self] floatItem in
        openFile()
    }

    floatItem.title = "title"

    Floaty.global.button.addItem(item: floatItem)
    Floaty.global.show()
}

func openFile() {   
    let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vcTitles =  storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "openFileViewController") as! OpenFileViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vcTitles, animated: true) 
}
```

Comment: Where is `openFile()`? Is it in the view controller currently being displayed by the navigation controller?

Comment: openFile() is in the same class as the setLayout(). I'm using this class as the view controller for the Floaty button. I'm instantiating this class in viewDidLoad on the first screen of my app as I need the button to show on all screens. I've learned that if I include this code in the view controller for my first screen instead of a separate file, it will present the view. So it must be because i'm not actually presenting this controller anywhere maybe?

Comment: *`self.navigationController?.pushViewController`* ... what is `self` there? If it's a view controller for the Floaty button, it sounds like it's not a view controller in your NavController hierarchy.

Comment: Yes, I think you are correct. I've moved this code into a view controller that I think should already be in the hierarchy and it's working. In this case, `self` is the view controller I instantiated in my initial view controller but was never presented.